# Display input selected value for particular card or element in vuejs?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js, html-input, html-datalist

I am displaying different cards with image and input element.

```
      <v-layout row wrap v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card width=500px>            
            <v-flex row xs2 class="py-3">
              <img :src="card.src" >
              <input type="search" v-model="search"
                 style="width:85px; border: 1px solid;"
                 placeholder="feel" list="choose" @change="input(search, card.id)" >
                <datalist id="choose">
                  <option v-for="source in filteredInput" :value="source" :key="source"></option>
                </datalist>
             </v-flex>
           </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
```

The problem is if I choose a value for card1 it is reflecting same value to all the cards without selecting them. I want to display input values based on input entered by the customer for that particular card.

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/62401/

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen that reproduce your issue ?

Comment: Wouldn't you put the v-for="card in cards" on the v-card element? We definitely need to see a snippet/codepen to see what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/62401 this is the link

Comment: You have `v-model="search"` on all inputs, so same value is reflected for all inputs. So you might want to convert `search` into array of strings, then bound each input to it's own v-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, you bind 'search' variable to all cards, which is the reason of your problem. To fix it simply change input's *v-model* property to i.e. 'card.value'. Now each card's value is stored seperately.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhr0d69q/

```html
<input type="search" v-model="card.value" style="width:85px; border: 1px solid;" placeholder="feel" list="choose" @change="input(card.value, card.id)">
```

Comment: Thank you @konrad kalemba. After selecting one value from datalist again we need to choose it again means selecting value 2 times. Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: @code.mevn https://jsfiddle.net/bhr0d69q/24/ Check it out. I gave unique ids to datalists as they all had it the same which led to the problem.

Comment: filteredInput has to return after user started typing and it has to return the value which exactly starts with the entered input.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhr0d69q/30/ this is my required one. Thank you @Konrad Kalemba

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed your v-model issue that you were having. You'll need to come up with a way to store the current id and get the value from search.

I've used an array as the model before. It works pretty well in situations like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/cgfhjmoy/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <v-layout row wrap v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="card.id">
        <v-flex xs12>
          <v-card width=500px>            
            <v-flex row xs2 class="py-3">
              <img :src="card.src" height="100px" width="100px">
              <input type="search" v-model="search[index]"
                 style="width:85px; border: 1px solid;"
                 placeholder="feel" list="choose" @change="input(search[index], card.id)" >
                <datalist id="choose">
                  <option v-for="source in filteredInput" :value="source" :key="source"></option>
                </datalist>
             </v-flex>
           </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
</div>
```

Then just set your `search` model to an array `search: []`

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. After selecting one value from datalist again we need to choose it means selecting value 2 times. Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Comment: @code.mevn, I know. Your question was about the v-model.